# Adjusting the position of an HTML span element based on prior content

Tags: html, css, css-position, pseudo-element

Here is the problem I am trying to handle.

- I need to show the original and the promotional price of an item on sale.
- Some items may not have any pricing - so nothing gets shown at all
- Some items might just indicate a price but no promotional price
- Items may optionally indicate their unit of price

When there is a price - and only when there is a price I want to append the pricing currency and, where available, the unit of price.  This is best understood by looking at the example below

```css
#spnOldPrice{text-decoration:line-through;}
#spnNewPrice{color:red !important;}
.pricing{position:relative;}
.pricing:not(:empty)::before
{
 position:absolute;
 left:100%;
 content:attr(data-label);
}
```

```html
<span id='spnOldPrice'><span id='plainoldPrice' class='pricing'>9.99</span></span>
<span id='spnNewPrice'><span id='plainnewPrice' class='pricing'>4.99</span></span>
<hr>
<span id='spnOldPrice'><span id='oldPrice' class='pricing' data-label='€/box'>9.99</span></span>
<span id='spnNewPrice'><span id='newPrice' class='pricing' data-label='€/box'>4.99</span></span>
```

I have two examples here

1. The first one simply indicates the full and the promotional price.  No issues here.
2. The second one indicates the full and the promotional price along with the currency and the unit of price

This latter example shows the problem.  The presence of the additional **€/box** string causes my conditional CSS rule `:not(:empty)::before`to kick in which cases the absolutely positioned `before` pseudo-element to show visible content.  Naturally, the following span - the promotional price - does not know anything about this pseduo element and draws itself under the **€/box** bit.

I can throw out the way I have done things here, use multiple nested spans and use a spot of JS to ensure that all works well all the time.  However, I wonder if there is a more elegant CSS only solution here.

Comment: Try with removing  position: absolute;left: 100% from .pricing:not(:empty):before css.

Comment: That simply has the effect of showing the currency/unit, e.g. €/box, to the LEFT of the actual price which is not at all what is intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `position: absolute` will create overwritten text, as stated by @UIDeveloper
If you want to show the value of an attribute *after* an element, just use the **`:after`** :pseudo.

*Note about accessibility:* (maybe you removed that part to have the shortest code possible for a question on SO) both prices will be read to blind screen reader users. They won't know that the first one is struck. To avoid that, you can add a span that'll only be perceivable by screen readers (with a class like `.visually-hidden` / `.element-invisible` / `.sr-only` already found in WP, Drupal, Bootstrap, etc) and an explanatory text: `<span class="visually-hidden">Old price</span>`

```css
#spnOldPrice{text-decoration:line-through;}
#spnNewPrice{color:red !important;}
/* .pricing{position:relative;} */
.pricing:not(:empty)::after
{
 /*position:absolute;*/
 /*left:100%;*/
 content:attr(data-label);
}
```

```html
<span id='spnOldPrice'><span id='plainoldPrice' class='pricing'>9.99</span></span>
<span id='spnNewPrice'><span id='plainnewPrice' class='pricing'>4.99</span></span>
<hr>
<span id='spnOldPrice'><span id='oldPrice' class='pricing' data-label='€/box'>9.99</span></span>
<span id='spnNewPrice'><span id='newPrice' class='pricing' data-label='€/box'>4.99</span></span>
```

---

**Variation:** flexbox allows to display flex items from right to left (and also bottom to top) by appending `-reverse`: `flex-direction: row-reverse` (it works because pseudo-elements are considered flex items).

```css
#spnOldPrice{text-decoration:line-through;}
#spnNewPrice{color:red !important;}
.pricing{
  display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end; /* which is... left-side! */
}
.pricing:not(:empty)::after
{
 content:attr(data-label);
}
```

```html
<span id='spnOldPrice'><span id='plainoldPrice' class='pricing'>9.99</span></span>
<span id='spnNewPrice'><span id='plainnewPrice' class='pricing'>4.99</span></span>
<hr>
<span id='spnOldPrice'><span id='oldPrice' class='pricing' data-label='€/box'>9.99</span></span>
<span id='spnNewPrice'><span id='newPrice' class='pricing' data-label='€/box'>4.99</span></span>
```

Comment: I tend to use `::before` as a matter of habit when I want to create unusual layouts that are somehow attached to another element and typically move the `::before` around as required by positioning it absolutely.  Clearly not required.  As [stated her](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) the after element would be the **last child** of its parent and would by default get positioned to the right anyway which is what I need here.  Nevertheless, I have accepted and upvoted your answer because I really like your flexbox solution.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way is to add a margin to the second span:

```css
#spnOldPrice{text-decoration:line-through;}
#spnNewPrice{color:red !important;}
.pricing{position:relative;}
.pricing:not(:empty)::before
{
 position:absolute;
 left:100%;
 content:attr(data-label);
}
#newPrice{margin-left: 40px;}
```

```html
<span id='spnOldPrice'><span id='plainoldPrice' class='pricing'>9.99</span></span>
<span id='spnNewPrice'><span id='plainnewPrice' class='pricing'>4.99</span></span>
<hr>
<span id='spnOldPrice'><span id='oldPrice' class='pricing' data-label='€/box'>9.99</span></span>
<span id='spnNewPrice'><span id='newPrice' class='pricing' data-label='€/box'>4.79</span></span>
```